# kernel_task at ~1000% on a 2019 macbook pro

Tags: temperature, kernel

I use a MacBook Pro 2019 and it increasingly often starts to run kernel_task at ~1000%. Fans are blowing too. I tried to cool down the computer with some additional device and also used Fan control to max the fans (but found out, they were already maxed).
The temperatures in the image below don't look so bad, I thought.

Its pretty annoying and happen at different times. As of this writing, I was almost unable to finish a Skype call because of this.

Sometimes I also see fractures in my Chrome browser. I wonder if this has something to do with the graphics card.[image]

What may cause this behaviour? And is there anything else I could check?

[image: MacSpecs]
[image: Mac Fan]

Comment: There are tens of questions about kernel_task with all sorts of troubleshooting steps. I've linked one I think is appropriate in this case, please [edit] with which Q&As you've tried already and their results.

Comment: Basically I have done all the steps mentioned in the other thread. I was actually searching for this. Nobody else had these blue screens. This was not helpful.